# multiple value matching for comparing input vs database?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

We are working on an internal inventory system. When a user orders and item from a vendor and puts in the order information, I want the users input of `brand`, `model`, `SKU`, etc to be free form input, then when submitted, it compares all of those values to items already in the inventory database. First it would compare the `SKU` if found then its a direct match. If not, then it moves on to comparing `model` and `brand` and asks the user to confirm they are the same item.

Does anyone have any ideas on best methods for accomplishing this? I cant even think of what this would be called to google it.
Code examples / resources would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your form field is named "orderInfo", and has the value "12345 Acme Gadget" (where 12345 is a valid SKU)

```
<cfquery name="checkSKU" datasource="inventoryDSN">
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 Inventory 
WHERE 
 cast(SKU as varchar) IN (<cfqueryparam value="#ListChangeDelims(form.orderInfo, ' ', ',')#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
</cfquery>

<cfif checkSKU.recordCount>
  <!--- We have a match! --->
<cfelse>

<cfquery name="checkOthers" datasource="inventoryDSN">
SELECT 
 inventory.*
FROM 
 Inventory 
WHERE 
 1=0
 <cfloop list="#form.orderInfo#" delimiters=" " index="searchTerm">
OR brand LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#searchTerm#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
OR model LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#searchTerm#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfloop>
</cfquery>

<cfif checkOthers.recordCount IS 1>
  <!--- have a solid match --->
<cfelseif checkOthers.recordCount GT 1>
  <!--- have some ambiguity, present user with choice among returned results --->
<cfelse>
  <!--- No match found, return error message --->
</cfif>
```